# Use c++ nuget in c# project

Tags: c#, c++, nuget

I have a question, can I use a nuget in c++, in a c# project?
is there any previous step or consideration that I have to take into account before using the c++ nuget?
or just I can call the methods and forget about the implementation ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be possible by Using "Platform Invocation":
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468(v=vs.71).aspx

It involves mapping functions to the dll produced by the C++ and so it might be more of a hassle then it solves.

I would advice searching for a other implementation of the nuget/functionality that is build for C# instead (like http://www.emgu.com/ does to wrap OpenCV)